# CPLEX primal infeasibility

Tags: matlab, mathematical-optimization, cplex

I'm running CPLEX (version 125) on MATLAB using the CPLEX API. I am trying to solve a Constrained Quadratic Programming problem, and I'm running into a primal infeasibility. In particular,the MATLAB code for the problem is:

```
[ystar, Jstar, flag, output]= ...
           cplexqp(H, f, F, phi, G, gamma, ymin, ymax);
```

which corresponds to the problem:

```
ystar = argmin_y    y'*H*y + f'*y
  subject to:
  ymin <= y <= ymax
  G * y = gamma
  F * y <= phi
```

However, the solution `ystar` returned by `cplexqcp` is such that:

```
 max(F*ystar-phi) = 5.1854e-05
```

I would like to decrease this infeasibility gap. I tried to change the primal feasibility bound, but it seems it doesn't have any effect:

```
 ops=cplexoptimset('cplex');
 ops.feasopt.tolerance=1e-7;
```

How can I configure the solver so as to level the infeasibility? The solver gives the following diagnostic messages:

```
Number of nonzeros in lower triangle of Q = 2622
Using Approximate Minimum Degree ordering
Summary statistics for factor of Q:
  Rows in Factor            = 4248
  Integer space required    = 4362
  Total non-zeros in factor = 27048
  Total FP ops to factor    = 334848
Tried aggregator 1 time.
QP Presolve eliminated 1128 rows and 114 columns.
Aggregator did 80 substitutions.
Reduced QP has 7984 rows, 8302 columns, and 129418 nonzeros.
Reduced QP objective Q matrix has 4134 nonzeros.
Parallel mode: using up to 8 threads for barrier.
Number of nonzeros in lower triangle of A*A' = 433356
Using Approximate Minimum Degree ordering
Summary statistics for Cholesky factor:
  Threads                   = 8
  Rows in Factor            = 7984
  Integer space required    = 32473
  Total non-zeros in factor = 556316
  Total FP ops to factor    = 62101602
 Itn      Primal Obj        Dual Obj  Prim Inf Upper Inf  Dual Inf          
   0   1.6154270e+04  -1.8807064e+06  1.92e+06  2.77e+05  5.03e+06
   1   1.7649880e+06  -4.6190853e+06  5.23e+05  7.57e+04  1.37e+06
   2   1.8883665e+06  -4.8518299e+06  1.30e+05  1.89e+04  3.42e+05
   3   8.3385088e+05  -2.9607988e+06  2.05e+04  2.97e+03  5.39e+04
   ... (some lines are omitted for brevity)
  31   9.9411620e+01   9.9411598e+01  1.10e-08  9.27e-10  4.32e-08
  32   9.9411615e+01   9.9411611e+01  1.37e-08  1.47e-10  6.85e-09
  33   9.9411614e+01   9.9411614e+01  2.19e-08  6.10e-12  2.51e-08
Barrier time = 1.91 sec. (361.06 ticks)    
Total time on 8 threads = 1.91 sec. (361.06 ticks)
```

So it seems that the primal infeasibility of the solution is `2.19e-08`; however, it seems that the solution is not that feasible.

**Update:** I normalised the equality and inequality constraints as follows:

```
F = F ./ kron( ones(1,size(F,2)), abs(phi) );
phi = sign(phi);
```

(Note: no element of `phi` is zero or near-zero. This way, all elements of `phi` become either `1` or `-1`.) and

```
for i=1:numel(gamma)
  if (abs(gamma(i))>1e-4)
    G(i,:) = G(i,:)/abs(gamma(i));
    gamma(i) = sign(gamma(i));
  end
end
```

The infeasibility I'm getting now is `5.577e-07` calculated as `max(F*ystar-phi)` (for the updated normalised matrices `F` and `phi`). Is CPLEX using an interior-point solver? If yes, there shouldn't be any infeasibility.

**Update 2:** I have uploaded the data for this problem and a test case [HERE](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/0f9edmutuyr2j8q/udBD_kbWHh).

Answer (score 2):

The parameter feasopt.tolerance applies to feasOpt, which is a separate algorithm intended for debugging models and won't affect the optimizer.  You want the parameter [EpRhs](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cosinfoc/v12r2/index.jsp?topic=/ilog.odms.cplex.help/Content/Optimization/Documentation/CPLEX/_pubskel/CPLEX980.html) which determines how much constraints can be violated in an optimal solution.
You can use [cplexoptimset](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cosinfoc/v12r2/index.jsp?topic=/ilog.odms.cplex.help/Content/Optimization/Documentation/CPLEX/_pubskel/CPLEX1198.html)('EpRhs', 1e-6')  to set the parameter.

Comment: Any idea on how to change this in MATLAB?

Comment: I tried it but it didn't work... `cplexoptimset` doesn't support this option (I also tried with lowercase characters).

Comment: @PantelisSopasakis try ops.simplex.tolerances.feasibility=1e-7

Comment: Are you assuming the problem is infeasible because the last line of the log has infeasibilities?  Did you check the [solution status](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cosinfoc/v12r2/index.jsp?topic=%2Filog.odms.cplex.help%2FContent%2FOptimization%2FDocumentation%2FCPLEX%2F_pubskel%2FCPLEX1131.html) after the solve?

Comment: The solution status is cplexstatusstring: 'optimal', cplexstatus: 1, message: 'Function converged to a solution x.'CPLEX doesn't return any errors. The last line of the log appears to have very low primal infeasibility, but the infeasibility I am calculating using the solution that CPLEX returns is higher. I uploaded the data for this problem as well as a test case at https://www.dropbox.com/sh/0f9edmutuyr2j8q/udBD_kbWHh

Comment: You are calculating an infeasiblity of ~1e-7.  Cplex's default tolerance is 1e-6, so this solution is feasible according to cplex.  You can set the tolerance to as low as 1e-9.

Comment: As you can see in the test case I posted at https://www.dropbox.com/sh/0f9edmutuyr2j8q/udBD_kbWHh, the primal infeasibility I'm calculating in as big as `9.3263e-04` (norm-infinity of `Fy-phi`). Both `ops.simplex.tolerances.feasibility` and `ops.EpRhs` (as suggested above) seem to have no effect on the solution. I also tried to change `ops.qpmethod`, but without any better results.